# My Neovim LSP error message doesn't have a red color

Tags: vim, neovim, language-server-protocol

My Neovim LSP error message doesn't have a red color:

[image: Neovim screenshot with diagnostic message]

Here is my vimrc file. I really don't know what the issue is.

```
syntax on

set guicursor=
set relativenumber
set noerrorbells
set tabstop=2 softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set smartindent
set nu
set nowrap
set smartcase
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
set incsearch
set cursorline
set cursorcolumn
set updatetime=50



call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'gruvbox-community/gruvbox'
Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'
Plug 'scrooloose/syntastic'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plug 'nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides'
Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'
Plug 'blueyed/vim-diminactive'
Plug 'mattn/emmet-vim'
Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
Plug 'mileszs/ack.vim'
"Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'
"Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'
"Plug 'peitalin/vim-jsx-typescript'
Plug 'neovim/nvim-lspconfig'
Plug 'nvim-lua/completion-nvim'

call plug#end()


let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark = 'hard'
if exists('+termguicolors')
    let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
endif
let g:gruvbox_invert_selection='0'

colorscheme gruvbox
set background=dark

let loaded_matchparen = 1
let mapleader = " "

let g:airline#extensions#tabline#enabled = 1
let g:fzf_layout = { 'window': { 'window': 0.8, 'height': 0.8 } }
let $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS='--reverse'

set completeopt=menuone,noinsert,noselect
let g:completion_matching_strategy_list = ['exact', 'substring', 'fuzzy']
lua require'nvim_lsp'.tsserver.setup{ on_attach=require'completion'.on_attach }

map <C-\> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
map <C-/> :TagbarToggle<CR>

nnoremap <leader>h :wincmd h<CR>
let g:gitgutter_map_keys = 0
nnoremap <leader>j :wincmd j<CR>
nnoremap <leader>k :wincmd k<CR>
nnoremap <leader>l :wincmd l<CR>
nnoremap <leader>pv :wincmd v<bar> :Ex <bar> :vertical resize 30<CR>
```

Comment: Try commenting out plugins one-by-one (as you have for `typescript-vim`, for example), to narrow it down to either: 1) Another plugin is interfering, and now you know which one or 2) another plugin is ***not*** interfering; either way, we'll be closer to diagnosing your problem.

Comment: yes typescript-vim was coloring my files. But it didn't affect the color of error message... can we possilby override the error msg by any chane? I don't think lsp has that feature though

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I removed `"Plug 'leafgarland/typescript-vim'` and it removed it fixed :D

Answer (score 9):

I am on Windows 10 and use the new Windows Terminal + NeoVim, my config is similar to yours with the same colorscheme. I fixed the color issue by adding this to my 'init.vim' file, before setting the colorscheme:

```
set termguicolors
```

The following options were recommended as a solution in different GitHub discussions, but they had no effect for me whatsoever:

```
let g:gruvbox_contrast_dark = 'hard'

if exists('+termguicolors')
    let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
    let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
endif

let g:gruvbox_invert_selection='0'
set background=dark
```

Answer (score 4):

To change the colors of diagnostic messages:

```
set termguicolors

hi DiagnosticError guifg=Red
hi DiagnosticWarn  guifg=DarkOrange
hi DiagnosticInfo  guifg=Blue
hi DiagnosticHint  guifg=Green
```

Setting `LspDiagnosticsVirtualTextError` did not change colors in my case.

To see the highlights that you're currently using, run `:hi`. Since the list of highlights can be pretty long, you might want to open that list in a Vim buffer for easier searching and navigating:

```
:enew|pu=execute('hi')
```

---

See also [this discussion](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues/516) on how to set LSP colors using Lua. The link was provided in a deleted answer to this question by user [Marcel Arie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14133028/marcel-arie).

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, the old answers will probably fail, now there are more organized highlight groups for you to customize the colors of those, for example:

```
highlight LspDiagnosticsDefaultError guifg=#FF0000
```

For more detailed information read `:help lsp-highlight-diagnostics` and `:help highlight`.

Edit: Notice this needs to go after more general colorscheme settings such as `colorscheme whatever` that might overwrite your highlight

Answer (score 2):

Here is the one that worked for me

```
hi LspDiagnosticsVirtualTextError guifg=Red ctermfg=Red
```

`guifg` is for GUI clients and  `ctermfg` is for terminal clients

This should work for both terminal and gui clients

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Plug 'folke/lsp-colors.nvim'
```